# ObjC How to display same JSON records based on their key in a single UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

The JSON from the backend is the following

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 108,
      "userId": "84945dd7-4ebe-418a-b5ec-bd418d226778",
      "notificationType": 0,
      "messagingService": 1,
      "status": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 109,
      "userId": "84945dd7-4ebe-418a-b5ec-bd418d226778",
      "notificationType": 0,
      "messagingService": 2,
      "status": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 110,
      "userId": "84945dd7-4ebe-418a-b5ec-bd418d226778",
      "notificationType": 1,
      "messagingService": 1,
      "status": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 111,
      "userId": "84945dd7-4ebe-418a-b5ec-bd418d226778",
      "notificationType": 1,
      "messagingService": 3,
      "status": 2
    }
  ]
```

I fetch the records to an Array from the backend

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *userPreferences;
```

What I want to succeed is to display those records with the same key "notificationType" in a single cell to present the different types of the other key "messagingService". And finally to tap on any indexPath.row and know which record I have choose and do my active/inactive option.

Comment: So, you want one row to represent all records grouped by `notificationType`?  I don't understand what you want to do beyond that

Comment: Yes i would like to combine/group them and show them (the common notificationTypes ones) to a single cell but what i get currently from the array is to populate them to many different cells, it looks like a repeated cell to the user

Comment: So I would handle this by creating  new mutable dictionary. Traverse `data` and for each dictionary therein, create a new key/value in your new mutable dictionary w/ key being the `notificationType` and value being an array of `messagingService` ids.  If the `notificationType` key already exists, append the messaging service to its value.

Comment: thank you for your example this is what i came up with :

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the message Jordan Bonitatisfor, based on your example this is what i came up with :

```
NSMutableDictionary *resultDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                for (int i = 0; i < [preferences count]; i++)
                {
                    if (resultDict[[preferences[i] valueForKey:@"notificationType"]]) {
                        //pull out the array and add to it
                        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: resultDict[[preferences[i] valueForKey:@"notificationType" ]]];
                        [mutableArray addObject:preferences[i]];
                        [resultDict setValue:mutableArray forKey:[preferences[i] valueForKey:@"notificationType" ] ];
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            NSArray *array = @[preferences[i]];
                            [resultDict setValue:array forKey:[preferences[i] valueForKey:@"notificationType" ] ];
                        }
                    }

                [self.foundPreferences addObject:resultDict];
```

How can i append the resultDict now to the proper cell .

Answer (score 0):

After hard testing and trial and errors i managed to succeed to exactly what i want with the help of Generics (never used them before) thx for all the help.

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSNumber*, NSMutableDictionary<NSNumber *, KYNotificationPreference *> *> *preferences = [NSMutableDictionary new];

                                       for(NSDictionary *rawPreference in (*response).data){
                                           KYNotificationPreference *preference = [KYDeserializer notificationPreferenceFromSerializedObject:rawPreference];
                                           NSMutableDictionary *notificationTypeDictionary = preferences[@(preference.notificationType)];
                                           if(!notificationTypeDictionary){
                                               notificationTypeDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
                                               [preferences setObject:notificationTypeDictionary forKey:@(preference.notificationType)];
                                           }
                                           [notificationTypeDictionary setObject:preference forKey:@(preference.messagingService)];
                                       }
```